# read Json contents on Restful webserver

Tags: java, json, rest

I have a JSON content as below and able to parse the data with following portion of code.However I have stored the content in a flat file and parsed it. Need to do the same when I get the request in Restful webserver.

Code to read from file:(Working)

```
data = new Gson().fromJson(new FileReader("/home/raj/apache-tomcat-8.0.3/webapps/file.json"), Data.class);
```

JSON data:

```
{
        "DeviceCommon": {
            "ASIdentifier": "123",
            "DatadeliveyMechanism": "notify",
            "MobileOriginatorCallbackReference": {
                "url": "http://application.example.com/inbound/notifications/modatanotification/"
            },
            "AccessiblityCallbackReference": {
                "url": "http://application.example.com/inbound/notifications/accessibilitystatusnotification"
            }
        },
        "DeviceList": [{
            "ExternalIdentifer": "123456@mydomain.com",
            "msisdn": "123456",
            "senderName": "Device1",
            "MobileOriginatorCallbackReference": {
                "notifyURL": "http://application.example.com/inbound/notifications/modatanotification/"
            },
            "ConfigurationResultCallbackReference": {
                "notifyURL": "http://application.example.com/inbound/notifications/configurationResult"
            },
            "ASreferenceID": "AS000001",
            "NIDDduration": "1d"
        }]
    }
```

POJO class(Data)

```
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

class Data {

    @SerializedName("DeviceCommon")
    DeviceCommon deviceCommon;

    @SerializedName("DeviceList")
    DeviceListEntry[] deviceList;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Data{" +
                "\n  deviceCommon=" + deviceCommon +
                "\n  deviceList=" + Arrays.toString(deviceList) +
                "\n}";
    }
}
```

REST server code(not working)

```
@POST
    @Path("/adddevice")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response  createConfigRequest(Data configRequest) {
             Gson gson = new Gson();
            String json = gson.toJson(Data.class);
            log.info("json string is"+json);
```

}

error:

```
Unrecognized field "DeviceCommon" (class com.AS.service.Data), not marked as ignorable (0 known properties: ])
 at [Source: org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderInterceptorExecutor$UnCloseableInputStream@724206cc; line: 2, column: 17] (through reference chain: com.affirmed.AS.service.Data["DeviceCommon"])
```

Comment: Are you trying to convert `configRequest` object to json? you should be passing in tha object to `gson.toJson`

Comment: I tried something as below but still not working                                            @POST
 @Path("/adddevice")
 @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
 @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
 public Response  createConfigRequest(Data configRequest) {
                                                        Data configRequest2 = new Data();
   Gson gson = new Gson();
         String json = gson.toJson(configRequest2);                              Tried with configRequest and configRequest2, getting the same error

Comment: Can anyone let me know what Iam doing wrong

Comment: Figured out the issue. In my POJO class setters/getters are missing. Its working after I added those.